# Alignment and parallax movement of elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

I am trying to do something like the picture below is showing.

[image]

Here is the explanation:

I have a div which has a max-width of 1920px. In there I have a grid of 8 columns. In there I want to align all Elements (divs with link wrap) from the middle to the left hand and the right hand side. The red elements are just there in place. But, and now comes my problem, the blue ones need to move just a little with some kind of parallax effects up and down.

The red elements are not a problem at the moment (except that the margin-top: -100px is looking like crap when scalling the window). But I can't get the blue ones to show at the right position and then move them with parallax.

**Important: all elements are added dynamically from a database. So I can't just do element-specified positioning.**

Now this is my code for one element:

```
<a href="#" class="work-elem-link">
   <div class="work-elem-content span2 fposrh">
      <div class="work-elem" data-pos="210" data-move="elem-fix">
          <div class="work-elem-img" data-img="1f-h_r">
              <img class="work-elem-imgtag" src="" style="visibility:hidden"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="work-elem-details">
          <div class="work-elem-details-title">TITLE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

In the Element "work-elem-content" is an image which is shown. If I hover the element, the element "work-elem-details" becomes visible and shows the title.

And this is the CSS Code to this element:

```
    .work-elem-content {
        position: relative;
        height: inherit;
    }
    .work-elem {
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: inherit;
    }
    .work-elem-img {
        background-size: 100% !important;
        display: block; 
    }
    img.work-elem-imgtag {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .work-elem-details {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 252, 163, 0.7);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;   
    }
    .work-elem-details-title {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'ArcherMedium';
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 18pt;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 50% 0;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
.fposlh {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.fposrh {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 25%;
}
.fposlq {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.fposrq {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.bposl1 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.bposl2 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
}
.bposr1 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.bposr2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
}
```

As you can see, I am trying different things but can't see trough my problem. Would be great if anyone can help me with this. I know the content of my question looks very big but it's not even that complex. I just tried to write down my question as clear as possible.

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

For a Graphic like this, I would let `clear` and `float` out and set the DIV-Container-Positions with `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` or `left`, `top`, `width` and `height`. Important for this: Set all DIV-Containers `display:block;`.
If you create some dynamic from a Database, wich is moving or got other Runtime-Effects, you need Javascript to set the CSS-Propertys.

```
<script>

var e = document.getElementById('divId');

e.style.display = 'block';
e.style.left = '50px';
e.style.top = '20%';
...

</script>
```

Use Variables for the Values ('block', '50px') to set new Propertys.

Comment: Thanks, but at the moment I see some problems with the responsive work and all this positioning. the other problem is, that I haven't a solution to do the positioning for the blue, and moving elements.